# Why select 1 with where returns 1 on failure

Tags: mysql, select

I have a command like this

```
    SELECT 1 from my_table where ip = INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') limit 1
```

When the given IP is not in the table, or even if the table is empty, the command returns 1. I've used a similar command before and it worked? Why is this returning 1 when it shouldn't?

Comment: How are you checking the return value?

Comment: instead of one make id or * and see the columns returend

Comment: Gordon - i'm checking the result of the select query for 1 or 0.  nbl - I know using * will work but that is not the question.